# gorilla/sessions persistent between server restarts?

Tags: session, go, gorilla

I have a general question about sessions. I am not very seasoned when it comes to this subject. I've tried with:

```
NewRediStore (gopkg.in/boj/redistore.v1)  
NewCookieStore  
NewFileSystemStore
```

I was under the impression that sessions could last between server restarts, hence the need for a 'store'. While my golang backend is running, I am able to set new sessions and retrieve them for multiple users/browsers. No problems there.

When I restart my server, I notice that all session access results in `session.IsNew == true`.
In Redis, I can see all the session keys after the restart, and even verified that `.Get`ting the session results in the right ID retrieved, but `IsNew` is still set.

I guess intuitively, this makes sense because there must be some map in memory that leads to the setting of `IsNew` but I would think that if there was any hit for the cookie key in the store, `IsNew` should not be set. Am I going crazy? Is there something easy that I am doing wrong? Is this a fundamental misunderstanding of how to use sessions?
Please let me know if I need to include code or additional details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have had the same assumptions you did, and browsing the source, it looks like it should work as you described. You might try debugging and stepping through it, particularly the `New` method for the store you're using (e.g. [`FilesystemStore.New`](https://github.com/gorilla/sessions/blob/master/store.go#L189) or [`RediStore.New`](https://github.com/boj/redistore/blob/v1.2/redistore.go#L232)). If that method successfully reads the cookie and finds the session in the store, it should set `IsNew = false`, according to the source.

Also note that just checking the session ID is not a good way of validating this behavior. If you look at the source, it decodes the session ID from the cookie, *then* tries to look that up in the backing store. If the lookup fails, then the session ID will match, but `IsNew` will be `true` and there won't be any values in the session. Make sure you're setting some value in the session and check for that instead of the session ID. The behavior is different for the `CookieStore` since it stores the session data in the cookie itself.

Comment: Interesting. Digging in to redistore, I saw [this](https://github.com/boj/redistore/blob/v1.2/redistore.go#L242) in the code and decided to print some stuff there. `ok == true` **and** `err == "gob: name not registered for interface: "gitlab.com/droneprime/spectre.host/server/internal/handlers.User""`  That seems like a strange error to get at this point in the code? It seems like that should be in my code?

Comment: I solved my issue. Not only do you have to register with `encoding/gob` when you put stuff in, but also when you try to access data. Thank you for encouraging me to poke in the library code. I will do that in the future first :)

Comment: @droneprime this fixed my issue. It seemed bizarre that my sessions were expiring after a server reboot, and I was getting that strange gob error in a place that made no sense. Registering with encoding/gob in the right place fixed my issue